# Resume streaming GZIP file after connection reset in Java

Tags: java, compression, streaming, gzip, gzipinputstream

Let's say my application needs to stream huge 100 GB+ GZIP compressed files over network. I assume that these files might often fail to be streamed in a single attempt because of connectivity problems. Therefore I'm looking for the way to be able to restore streaming from point it failed. I know that GZIP out of the box doesn't allow streaming from the middle of the file. But I assume it has the state that can be serialized. Then having that state, it should be possible to restore GZIP reader to the state it was before failure and continue streaming from the failure point.

I would appreciate any experience/thoughts on how this can be achieved. I've looked at GZIPInputStream and stuck ending up facing native methods in Inflater class and reading RFCs.

Comment: GZIP the files locally and then use HTTP of FTP ranges to send them.

Comment: I don't have control over these files, I get them as URL. It's possible to say that my application doesn't work with files bigger than, say, 100GB, but ideally I would prefer to push this limit higher.

Answer (score -1):

How do you solve a big problem? divide them into tiny chunks. here is my initial take on this not know a whole lot of background in regards the type of file, network latency, frequency of transfer etc.

Here is what I would do.

1. Break down that file into very small chunks. For simplicity 1GB each.
2. Rename these files uniquely and also serially. Example {uuid}-1, {uuid}-2 etc
3. Save this metadata in a datastore. basically you want to keep track of all the small chunks you've created. Here is what the meta data could look like.

```js
[{
"file_name" : "b006194c-80ba-11e8-adc0-fa7ae01bbebc--1",
"size" : "1 GB",
"status" : "done"  
},
{
"file_name" : "dc903236-80ba-11e8-adc0-fa7ae01bbebc--2",
"size" : "1 GB",
"status" : "in_progress"  
}
]
```

4. Then you start move these chunks across the network. Doesn't matter which one you pick first or if you pick multiple at the same as long as you have the bandwidth.
5. If any of the chunks fail you can retry that chunk not having to redo the whole thing.
6. You put them together (you have the order too on how you can put it together).

Good luck.

Comment: My application only consumes files, I don't have control over producing them. I get them as URLs, so to split them I need to firstly download them. And it's where the original problem occurs.

Comment: Oh wow. I wasn't aware. However, I wouldn't have put that large of a file like that in the first place without putting in a proper mechanism on how people would retrieve them programmatically.  

What I'm trying to say is for example, if you were to store 100 GB of file in amazon S3 I know that I'll have an SDK to retrieve them in parts. here is the doc https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/RetrievingObjectUsingJava.html  that shows how to do it.  If you can work with the folks who store it and see if you can find a better way.